# Importing ES6 modules in deep directories

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Given this directory tree:

```
components
  foo
    index.js
    bar
      index.js
```

Using babel es6, I would like to do this:

```
import Foo from "./components/foo"
import Bar from "./components/foo/bar"
```

But it errors with `Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/jemminger/Development/whatever/components/foo/bar.js'`

The only way I can get it to work is this:

```
import Foo from "./components/foo"
import Bar from "./components/foo/bar/index"
```

or

```
import Foo from "./components/foo"
import Bar from "./components/foo/bar/"
```

According to https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules I should be able to load the `index.js` file of a directory by default, which happens for `foo` but not `bar`.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Not expected. The same setup works fine for me, using `babel-node`.

Comment: Hmm, maybe a bug with generator-react-webpack then.  I'll try there.

Comment: Babel just compiles to CommonJS. The ES6 module system doesn't actually define or care what the module identifiers represent (e.g. paths in this case). Whatever the issue is, it has nothing to do with ES6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not sure what the cause of the problem was, but in attempting to replicate the issue today in the same project, it's working as expected.  Perhaps just the fact that webpack-dev-server was restarted fixed it.  Apparently I can't computer.

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs imports your files realatively, so you always need to care about current path. If you want to start your import path from the same point, try to use webpack. It has [`resolve.root`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root) option, which do exactly what you want. Just set your components root:

```
resolve: {
    root: [
        __dirname
    ]
}
```

I am assuming that `webpack.config.js` will be placed next to `components` dir. Then you can do imports as you want, but without leading `./`:

```
import Foo from "components/foo"
import Bar from "components/foo/bar"
```

Be aware that now you have collission between npm-module `components` and your file. Your code will have priority in that case.